# how to store array data in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I wanted the user to enter any alphabet in a text field, when he/she clicks on the `Find!` button, it will go through my php file and find a list of words that start with that alphabet (of course it's only a limited amount of words). And I want to output it to a table, with 5 columns, each cell containing one word.

Something like this:

[image: 5columns]

> **in my HTML:**

```
  <label>
    Enter any alphabet:
      <input name="alphabet" type="text" id="alphabet"></label>
      <input type="button" value="Find!" id="goFind">

<table border="1" id="output">
</table>
```

> **and Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
  });

  var bunchOfWords = function (data) {
    var listOfWords = "";

    if(!Array.isArray(data)) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      for(i = 0; i < data.length; i = +5) {
        listOfWords += "<tr><td>" + data[i] + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + data[i] + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + data[i] + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + data[i] + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + data[i] + "</td></tr>";
      }
    }
  };

  $("#goFind").click(function () {
    var theWord = $("#alphabet").val();
    $("#output").html("Loading...");  //gives the user an indication that it's loading
    $.getJSON("wordslookup.php", "startswith=" + theWord, listOfWords);
  });
});
```

Can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Describing what happens instead of the expected result would help... Did you at least look at your browser's dev tools/error console?

Answer (score 0):

`listOfWords` is out of scope in `$.getJSON` also its not a function, you should pass `bunchOfWords` to `$.getJSON` instead. To put the data in the table simply replace the current inner html, `$("#output").html(listOfWords);`